# How do I find and replace substrings through regular expressions in Matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I am using Matlabs regular expression function regexprep() to find and replace strings in a .c file
I have been trying to take the following strings in the .c file:

```
var[12] = powmacro(var[11],"name11",var[25],"name25");

var[13] = divmacro(var[23],"name23",var[12],"name12");
```

...and convert them to the following format:

```
var[12] = var[11]^var[25]

var[13] = var[23]/var[12]
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: If this is a one time process, you shouldn't be using matlab script

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code:

```
% regular expression patterns
re_sp = '\s*';
re_str = [re_sp '"[^"]*"' re_sp];
re_var = [re_sp '(var\[\d+\])' re_sp];
re_pow = [re_var '=' re_sp 'powmacro' re_sp '\(' ...
    re_var ',' re_str ',' re_var ',' re_str ')' re_sp ';'];
re_div = [re_var '=' re_sp 'divmacro' re_sp '\(' ...
    re_var ',' re_str ',' re_var ',' re_str ')' re_sp ';'];

% replace patterns in strings
str = {'var[12] = powmacro(var[11],"name11",var[25],"name25");' ;
    'var[13] = divmacro(var[23],"name23",var[12],"name12");'};
str = regexprep(str, re_pow, '$1 = $2 ^ $3');
str = regexprep(str, re_div, '$1 = $2 / $3');
disp(str)
```

The result:

```
>> str
str = 
    'var[12] = var[11] ^ var[25]'
    'var[13] = var[23] / var[12]'
```